# how to delete the toolbar in android design

Tags: android

[The red frame should not have in my code, but after I updated my Android Studio, it is showed in all of my APPS. please click and see the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oto4n.png)

How to delete the red frame from my code? And it could not find in its design/text.  The blue frame's begin code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/activity_login_user_email_edt"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"

        android:paddingLeft="35dp"

        android:autoText="true"

        android:hint="e-mail" />
```

Comment: Set activity to full screen

Comment: There is a Theme Option At the top of the Virtual Device preview in xml near to screen orientation and select device. Click on that and select Holo.LIght.NoActionBar

Comment: set activity with  Holo.LIght.NoActionBar or  Holo.LIght.NoActionBar.FullScreen are not useful. I had tried, it still has part of red frame when I build on my phone.

Comment: did you tried running it for once? might not be there while you run it

Comment: I had tried, and run it on the phone, light / dark just change the color of the bar, and another theme I had tired, there are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer Skynet posted is correct,but this is the programatical way

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Full Screen and remove toolbar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it was ok. O(∩_∩)O

Answer (score 0):

That is the theme your activity is extending from. You change it in the styles.xml. Then you need to update this setting in the Manifest.

You need to add this to styles.xml:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

</style>
```

Then in your AndroidManifest.xml for this Activity:

```
       <activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
        </activity>
```

The above will work if you are extending from `AppCompatActivity` which should look like:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{}
```

Comment: I had tried, but it still has the part of red frame.    android:screenOrientation="landscape", this will change the direction to landscape, it is redundant.

Comment: You can remove the `landscape` attribute - that was for example sake.